# Unable to add Custom ribbon on share point default landing page

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, ribbon

I am trying to **add custom ribbon** on the default home page of the sharepoint online site. For some of the site collection the home page '*default.aspx*' shows the custom ribbon but for some of other site collections the home page'*default.aspx*' doesn't show the custom ribbon although if I am going to list/libarry of this site collection the custom ribbon appears.

**I am using below CSOM PowerShell to add custom ribbon. Please suggest me If anything I am missing:**

```
#Import these dlls for CSOM powershell
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Tenant admin URL
$AdminURL = "https://test-admin.sharepoint.com"

#Credentials required for connecting admin tenant
$UserName = "abc@abc.com"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "abcd" –asplaintext –force
#$SecurePWD = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$SPOCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $Password)  

#Path for csv file
$ConnectionsPath = "D:\AKARi\Migration\Connections\Connections.csv"

#Import csv file
$connections = Import-Csv -Path $ConnectionsPath

#Iterate through all items in csv file
foreach($connection in $connections)
{
#Creating context by connecting to a destination URL
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($connection.DestinationURL)

$ctx.credentials = $SPOCredentials  
$web = $ctx.Site.RootWeb  
$userActions = $web.UserCustomActions  
$ctx.Load($userActions)   
$ctx.ExecuteQuery() 

#If any custom action is already created, it will be deleted
$itemsToDelete = @()  
if($userActions.Count -le 0){  
    Write-Host "No Ribbon Items found to delete"  
}  
else{  
    foreach($userAction in $userActions){  
        $itemsToDelete += $userAction                  
    }  
    foreach($item in $itemsToDelete){  
        Write-Host "Deleting Ribbon Item : " $item.Title  
        $item.DeleteObject()  
    }  
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  
}   

#code for adding a new custom action to ribbon container  
$newRibbonItem = $userActions.Add()  
$newRibbonItem.RegistrationId = "0x01"  
$newRibbonItem.Title = "Custom Ribbon Tab"  
$newRibbonItem.RegistrationType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserCustomActionRegistrationType]::ContentType  
$newRibbonItem.Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon" 

#Variables for image path 
$varImageUrlInternal ="https://test1.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/akari_new%20logo_64x64.png"
$varImageUrlExternal ="https://test1.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/akari_new%20logo_external_64x64.png"

#Flag which states that the script will be executed for Internal sites, change it to External if it is to be executed for External sites
$varSiteCategory = "Internal"

if($varSiteCategory -eq "Internal")  
{
$ribbonUI = '<CommandUIExtension>  
                    <CommandUIDefinitions>  
                        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children">  
                           <Tab Id="Ribbon.Tab" Title="AKARi" Description="Custom Tab with groups and user action" Sequence="10" >  
                                <Scaling Id="Ribbon.Tab.Scaling">  
                                    <MaxSize Id="Ribbon.Tab.CustomGroup1.MinSize"  
                                        GroupId="Ribbon.Tab.CustomGroup1"  
                                        Size="LargeLayout" />  
                                </Scaling>  
                                <Groups Id="Ribbon.Tab.CustomGroups"> 
                                    <Group Id="Ribbon.Tab.CustomGroup1"  
                                        Description="Collection of user actions"  
                                        Title="Information"  
                                        Sequence="20"  
                                        Template="Ribbon.Templates.LargeLayout">  
                                        <Controls Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup1.Controls">

                                            <Button Id="Ribbon.Tab.CustomGroup1.ShowAlert" Alt="Show Alert" Sequence="10000"  
                                                 Command="ShowRibbonAlert"  
                                                 LabelText="This is an AKARi internal site"  
                                                 TemplateAlias="ButtonTemplate" 
                                                 Image32by32="' + $varImageUrlInternal + '" 

                                                 />  
                                        </Controls>  
                                    </Group>  
                                </Groups>  
                            </Tab> 

                       </CommandUIDefinition>  
                        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">   
                            <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.LargeLayout">   
                                <Layout Title="LargeLayout" LayoutTitle="LargeLayout">   
                                    <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">   
                                        <Row>   
                                            <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="ButtonTemplate" />   
                                        </Row>   
                                    </Section>   
                                </Layout>   
                            </GroupTemplate>   
                        </CommandUIDefinition>  
                    </CommandUIDefinitions>  
                    <CommandUIHandlers>  
                        <CommandUIHandler Command="ShowRibbonAlert"  
                             CommandAction="" />  
                    </CommandUIHandlers>  
                </CommandUIExtension >'
}
else
{
                $ribbonUI = '<CommandUIExtension>  
                    <CommandUIDefinitions>  
                        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children">  
                           <Tab Id="Ribbon.Tab" Title="AKARi External" Description="Custom Tab with groups and user action" Sequence="10" >  
                                <Scaling Id="Ribbon.Tab.Scaling">  
                                    <MaxSize Id="Ribbon.Tab.CustomGroup1.MinSize"  
                                        GroupId="Ribbon.Tab.CustomGroup1"  
                                        Size="LargeLayout" />  
                                </Scaling>  
                                <Groups Id="Ribbon.Tab.CustomGroups"> 
                                    <Group Id="Ribbon.Tab.CustomGroup1"  
                                        Description="Collection of user actions"  
                                        Title="Information"  
                                        Sequence="20"  
                                        Template="Ribbon.Templates.LargeLayout">  
                                        <Controls Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup1.Controls">

                                            <Button Id="Ribbon.Tab.CustomGroup1.ShowAlert" Alt="Show Alert" Sequence="10000"  
                                                 Command="ShowRibbonAlert"  
                                                 LabelText="This is an AKARi external site"  
                                                 TemplateAlias="ButtonTemplate" 
                                                 Image32by32="' + $varImageUrlExternal + '"
                                                 />  
                                        </Controls>  
                                    </Group>  
                                </Groups>  
                            </Tab> 

                       </CommandUIDefinition>  
                        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">   
                            <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.LargeLayout">   
                                <Layout Title="LargeLayout" LayoutTitle="LargeLayout">   
                                    <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">   
                                        <Row>   
                                            <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="ButtonTemplate" />   
                                        </Row>   
                                    </Section>   
                                </Layout>   
                            </GroupTemplate>   
                        </CommandUIDefinition>  
                    </CommandUIDefinitions>  
                    <CommandUIHandlers>  
                        <CommandUIHandler Command="ShowRibbonAlert"  
                             CommandAction="" />  
                    </CommandUIHandlers>  
                </CommandUIExtension >'
}  
$newRibbonItem.CommandUIExtension = $ribbonUI  
$newRibbonItem.Update()  
$ctx.Load($newRibbonItem)  
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()  
Write-Output "Branding applied"
}
```